# How to display information from _id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, ejs

I have `app.get` route to display an item document that contains _id, name, description. Here's what I currently have:

```
app.get('/itemEdit/:itemID', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    //console.log("params", req.params)
    const item_id  = req.params.itemID
    //console.log("ID", item_id)
    //Here you could query the db and find the item in the array on the user object
    User.find({ _id: req.user._id },
        (err, docs) => {
            // console.log(docs[0].userInventory)
            if (err) { console.log(`error: ${err}`) }
            else {
                console.log(docs);
                //You could render edit item page form then make a post route where you query the db and update the item
                res.render('itemEdit.ejs', {item_id, docs})
            }
        })
        console.log("Item query", item_id)
})
```

I know that this is grabbing the correct item as my `console.log` displays the correct id. Then, I try to display the data but this is where I'm hitting a wall. I have the `item id` but how to display the name and description that is in that same item? I tried as so:

```
<table>
    <!-- Table Headers -->
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- Table Data -->
        <tr>
            <td><%= userInventory[item_id].name %></td>
            <td><%= userInventory[item_id].description %></td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
</table>
```

This gives me an error: `SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

userSchema:

```
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    userInventory: [{
            name: String,
            description: String
    }]
});
```

Comment: your query has errors `{ _id: req.user._id, _id: item_id }`, you're trying to query by `_id` but you are passing two different values for `_id`. Also,  `res.render('itemEdit.ejs', {item_Id})` only sends `item_Id` to your view which is the value of `req.params.itemID`. You should send the `docs`

Comment: can you post your user schema, that would help with answering your question

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that error! I see now what you mean about only sending the item_id. I will try with docs now!

Comment: @knicholas I added the userSchema.

Comment: @knicholas I removed the extra value being passed on to `_id` and passed `docs` into the render but I'm still getting the same error. I think I need to change how I'm displaying the data in the form.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your route `'/itemEdit/:itemID'` should query for that item based on the `itemID` being passed in params and return the item.

*schemas*: I suggest changing your schemas to be something like this

**Item schema**

```
{
name: String,
description: String
....
}
```

reference to the item schema in `userInventory`

**User schema**

```
{
    username: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    userInventory: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'item'
    }]
}
```

Then your api should be something like:

```
app.get('/itemEdit/:itemID', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    const item_id  = req.params.itemID
    Item.findById(item_Id,
        (err, doc) => {
            if (err) { console.log(`error: ${err}`) }
            else {
                res.render('itemEdit.ejs', doc)
            }
        })
        console.log("Item query", item_id)
})
```

**itemEdit.ejs**

```
<table>
    <!-- Table Headers -->
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- Table Data -->
        <tr>
            <td><%= doc.name %></td>
            <td><%= doc.description %></td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
</table>
```